# How to obtaint the value of id f_prod_id from this html table?

Tags: jquery, oracle-apex

**this is my table from where i want to obtain the current f_prod_id value but when i display the alert to show the value, all i get is a null message...

any tips please...
thanks in advance**

```
<div class="Productos" >
<table id="products" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<thead>
<tr><th class="left">Prod</th><th><center>Desc</center></th><th>qty</th><th>Price</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td><a href="javascript:popUp2('some_link_here','700','400');"><input type="text" name="f_prod_id" size="10" value="5060102" readonly></td><td class="left">desc1</a></td><td><input type="number" name="f_qty" min="1" max="9999" step="1"></td><td>35.17</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="javascript:popUp2('some_link_here','700','400');"><input type="text" name="f_prod_id" size="10" value="5060101" readonly></td><td class="left">desc2</a></td><td><input type="number" name="f_qty" min="1" max="9999" step="1"></td><td>18.48</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

**And this is my Script, but the alert display nothing**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Totalizar</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() 
{


        $("#Calculate").click
           (

// move value
            function()
             {
              $("input[name=f_qty]").each
                (
                 function()
                   {
                     var valueInCurrentTextBox = $(this).val(); 
                      var productId = $(this).find(".f_prod_id").text();

                     if (valueInCurrentTextBox != '')
                        {
                          $("#P23_qty").val(valueInCurrentTextBox);     
                          alert('codid : ' + (productId));
                       }
                    }
                );
              }




           );

}
);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="totals"></div>
<p style="clear: both;">
<button type="button" style="font-weight: bold; width: auto;" id="Calculate">Agregar Productos</button></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a class named f_prod_id.  You have elements with a name of f_prod_id.  So you'll need to search for them by name:
    $("input[name='f_prod_id']")
instead of $('.f_prod_id')

If you are trying to find the f_prod_id in the same row as your f_qty input, you'll need something like this:

```
$("input[name=f_qty]").each(function () {
    var valueInCurrentTextBox = $(this).val();
    var productId = $(this).parents('tr').find("input[name=f_prod_id]").val();
    alert(productId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name='f_prod_id']").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

should do the trick.